# Why under the Axiom of Determinacy does the additive group $\mathbb{R}$ have no non-trivial direct summand?

Tags: continuity, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Page 154 of "The Axiom of Choice" by Herrlich states the proof as follows:

Assume $\mathbb{R}$ can be expressed as a direct sum $A\oplus B$ of two non-zero subgroups. The the map $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined by $f(a+b)=a$ for $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, is a non-continious solution of the equation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, contradicting prop. 7.18.

(where 7.18 states Under the AD all solutions of the Cauchy-equation are continious.)

I'm a bit confused by this proof. Prehaps I don't fully understand what a non-trivial direct summand is, but mostly I am confused as to why $f(a+b)=a$ is a non-continuous solution to the Cauchy equation. Continuity of the CE implies $f(x)=f(1) \cdot x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, is this detail relevant to my understanding here?

Thanks in advance, this is my first question!

Comment: $\mathbb R = A \oplus B$ means $A$ and $B$ are additive groups and every member of $\mathbb R$ can be expressed in a unique way as $a+b$ with $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.  Nontrivial in this case means neither $A$ nor $B$ is $\{0\}$.  
Do you not understand why $f$ is a solution?  It is certainly not continuous, because as you said the only continuous solutions are $f(x) = f(1) \cdot x$, and this is certainly not that.

Comment: Thank you! I certainly did not know enough about the notation of $\oplus$ and this has been really helpful. Now I can also understand why $f(a+b)=a$ is non-continuous. But yes, if you wouldn't mind, how is it a solution?